# How to Bold Text - Non-HTML Way?

Tags: formatting, ascii, rightnow-crm, oracle-service-cloud

### Case Scenario

I'm storing some textual data into database which cannot contain HTML tags. For line breaks, I'm using `\r\n` and the output is fine when I view it in a tool known as **Service Cloud (FKA RightNow)**

Similarly, is there a way in which I can bold a part of text using a similar technique as `\r\n`?

Comment: Would \_basic\_ \*\*markdown\*\* be useful?

Comment: @TomBlodget Nope. Doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where are you storing this text?  If this is a field that supports rich text, like standard text, then you can bold the text through rich text encoding.  However, you're likely working with a generic text (ASCII characters) field, which does not have formatting.  If that's the case, then no, you cannot format it.

Comment: Hi Scott. The text is being stored as an Incident Thread (`$incident->Threads[0]->Text`). I'm not sure if this supports rich text. Could you please confirm the same?

Comment: Threads do support rich text.  You should be able to apply rich text encoding to your text for formatting.

Comment: That's great news. Unfortunately using `**` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Take a look at this tutorial to see if it helps. http://www.pindari.com/rtf1.html

Comment: The link does not show a way of bold-ing text but your inputs are good enough for me.